# Substitute the Content of a file in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, vim, sed

I'm in Red Hat Linux machine, need to apply inside a file the following stuff:

This is what I have:

```
42506F0BB83839
```

need to be transformed like following:

```
^S:CELL:42506F0BB83839.*$       WM_PLUTO
```

where WM_PLUTO is tab separated.
Normally I'm editing the file with vim and apply something like

```
:%s /^4250/\^S:CELL:lost from this point on
```

How to do this ?
Please note that I have multiple lines like that, all of them have fix part `42506F0BB8` and the last 4 digits will change and can't be repeated, they are not the only lines, there are others with different details.
So, need to detect all the fix part amongthe lines and aplly substitution.

Comment: What's your input and expected output?

Comment: correct:currently I have something like ^S:CELL:425060BB814001.*$       WMHOME_PLUTO
^S:CELL:425060BB814002.*$       WMHOME_PLUTO
^S:CELL:425060BB814003.*$       WMHOME_PLUTO. I need to transform it in something like ^S:CELL:42506F0BB846D4.*$       WMHOME_Hebron
^S:CELL:42506F0BB846D5.*$       WMHOME_Hebron
^S:CELL:42506F0BB83AA3.*$       WMHOME_Hebron

Comment: @MorganForever edit your function, add what you have, what you want to get. don't put those info in comment.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace "lost from this point on" with `&`.  In the replacement, `&` will be replaced with whatever was matched.

```
:%s /^4250.*/\^S:CELL:&.*$<tab>WM_PLUTO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
sed 's/42506F0BB8..../\^S:CELL:&\.\*\$\tWM_PLUTO/' file
```

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake into description. Fix PArt is 42506F0BB8 then I have 500 lines that change the last 4 digit, so I have 42506F0BB83839 , 42506F0BB81234 etc etc. Thks for answering but of course as I was wrong your suggestion does not work :-(

Comment: just add 4 dots instead those numbers. I'll edit answer @morgan-forever

Comment: correct:currently I have something like             425060BB814001
425060BB814002                                                       
Need to have as outpunt                        ^S:CELL:425060BB814001.*$       WMHOME_PLUTO.                       ^S:CELL:42506F0BB84002.*$       WMHOME_Hebron
This is applied for 500 different lines

Comment: you can change one digit with [0-9] instead puting dot @morgan-forever
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLcUid3OP_4OW-rwv_mBHzx9MmE5TxvvcQ